# Is there a resource that explains how the LINQ to objects operators are implemented?

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

I just had an interesting exchange about using .Except versus .Any, and the performance difference between them.

I'm wondering if there is a resource online that explains the different implementations of LINQ to objects, and what the performance implications are.

I checked MSDN and hookedonlinq.com, and neither mentions that .Except builds a HashSet, whereas using array.Any(item => otherarray.Contains(item)) will simply iterate the second array for each item  - performance of  O(n²) for .Any vs O(n) for .Except

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely - my [Edulinq](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx) series :)

More precisely, that's a blog series about how LINQ to Objects *can* be implemented, with various discussions around performance etc. I'm not going to guarantee that the "real" implementation always takes the same route... but I wouldn't expect them to differ wildly.

As well as each operator being covered individually, the latest posts are more general, talking about performance trade-offs etc.

Comment: +1 Your blog series has been a fantastic read so far.  Would you think of making a new book based on the series?  I think it'd be great if you did.

Comment: @DoctaJonez: There are some ideas up in the air in terms of what to do with it. Don't worry, something will happen :)

Answer (score 2):

While there isn't a source how exactly the framework is implemented (except for reflector), there is [EduLinq](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx?PageIndex=3), courtesy of Jon Skeet. It is a long (nearly 50 blog entries) reimplementing all LINQ operators to explain how it works.